# What is the type of map.map in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typing

I want to find the type of map.map. The first image is a solution that i have found, but i don't quite get. My solution would have been like in the second image, but it is wrong. I do not understand the marked bit of the solution. Why is it like that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your blue comment would be true if we had `map1 :: ((d -> e) -> [d]) -> [e]` but we have instead `map1 :: (d -> e) -> ([d] -> [e])` since implicitly `->` associates on the right.

Comment: Never seen someone use rainbow scratchboard to do homework. I like it.

Comment: This question doesn't work with screen readers.

Comment: `map . map` = `\ f -> map (map f)` (by the definition of `(.)`), which you could eta-expand into `\ f xss -> map (\ xs -> map f xs) xss`—in other words, it’s mapping over the interior lists in a list of lists. Can be generalised to any functor: given `fmap2 = fmap . fmap`, `fmap2 succ [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2]` = `[Just 2, Nothing, Just 3]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: the arrow type constructor `(->)` is a *right associative* operator.

The arrow is right associative. This means that if you write:

```
map :: (d -> e) ->  [d] -> [e]
```

more verbose, you wrote:

```
map :: (d -> e) -> ([d] -> [e])
```

So given the first parameter of `(.)` has type `(a -> b)`, this thus means that the type `(d -> e) -> ([d] -> [e]) ~ a -> b` (`~` means the same type), and thus `a ~ d -> e` and `b ~ [d] -> [e]`. The same of course holds when we type check with the second `map`.

With that in mind we thus, like the nodes say derive:

```
(.) map map :: (f -> g) -> ([[f]] -> [[g]])
```

This thus means that this function takes a function of type `f -> g`, and maps all the elements in the lists of a list to a list of lists maintaining the structure.

For example:

```
Prelude> (.) map map (+1) [[1,4,2,5], [], [1,3], [2]]
[[2,5,3,6],[],[2,4],[3]]
```